# Bash run a command before previous ssh command has finished

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh

I am trying to program a shutdown protocol for a UPS that powers two servers. I want server A to trigger a bash script on server B over SSH. The script that I'm testing works pretty well at triggering server B, but I am having trouble with the script waiting for a reply from SSH before moving on to the rest of the script. Here is my server A script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@192.168.1.20 "/bin/bash /opt/shutdown.sh"

sleep 10
echo "start shutdown" | wall
shutdown -p now
```

I think I need the first line to run detached? I've done some searching and I've tried `nohup` and also adding `&` at the end of the ssh line. I've also tried using `screen` without any luck. I'd like the script to just move on as soon as it calls the ssh command. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use `ssh user@192.168.1.20 "/bin/bash /opt/shutdown.sh" &`? It should move on, without waiting for the remote command to terminate, unless you run it in an interactive shell.

Comment: Actually, I'm just a total idiot... I've been editing the wrong script for the last two days haha. But your solution did work! Thanks. If you want to throw it in an answer I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 2):

according to the ssh man:

```
 -f      Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to ask
         for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies -n.  The recom‐
         mended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
```

I think `ssh -f user@192.168.1.20 "/bin/bash /opt/shutdown.sh"` might solve your problem
cheers!